How to correctly upsample a signal in code/python for baseband simulation?
When I upsample I am stuffing with zeros in between symbols but this creates a bunch of data points around zero in the constellation for the signal and this doesnt seem correct but im not sure. is there another step I am missing?
# generate bit sequence:
bits = np.random.randint(0, 2, N_bits)
modem = get_modem(mod_type)
symbols = modem.modulate(bits)
# upsample
signal = np.zeros(len(symbols) * sps, dtype='complex')
signal[::sps] = symbols
# pulse shape
time, psf_coeff = rrcosfilter(filter_length, roll_off, Ts, Fs)
signal = sig.convolve(signal, psf_coeff)
# add awgn noise
real_signal = add_awgn(signal,SNR)
return real_signal


please include what all your parameters actually are

Without seeing the actual parameters it's not clear what is being generated or what the question is, but I will make an attempt:
Assuming the OP is attempting to generate a QPSK waveform with Root Raised Cosine Filtering, the plot as shown may be correct. This would be the waveform generated at the transmitter, which would then pass through a second Root Raised Cosine filter in the receiver, resulting in a Raised Cosine filtered waveform similar to the high SNR waveform I have plotted below.
Here we see red dots at the "ideal" sampling locations once per symbol, but the waveform as generated would have more than one sample per symbol in order to realize the pulse shape providing the nice spectral containment as necessary for over the air transmission. Thus there will be more samples along the blue trajectories shown between those red dots, depending on how many samples per symbol are used in the digital part of the design.

Further, the Root Raised Cosine result will NOT have the nice tight dots as we show in my graphic above, and depending on the bandwidth factor used for the pulse shaping, will be spread similar to what we might be seeing in the OP's plot. I show this below comparing the eye diagrams for an RRC filtered QPSK waveform on the left to that of an RC filtered waveform on the right (which is what we get after the RRC waveform passed through the second RRC waveform in the receiver.

Even if the resulting waveform is sampled once per symbol, if there is a timing offset such that the samples are not at the ideal locations (as indicated by the minimum spread locations in the eye diagrams shown), then we will also have an opportunity to get a result similar to what the OP has shown.
